# What is the meaning of the phrase "failure to fail"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, translation

What is the meaning of the phrase "failure to fail"?,

> And If I close now by professing that abject/ecstatic failure to
>   fail, it is only by way of reminding myself..."

Comment: It sounds like a simple case of artistic usage. Please provide more context and add lines from the excerpt if you can.

Comment: If the speaker is  an entrepreneur giving his talk in a startup context, he may be riffing on the (now cliched) mantra "*fail fast*", and using "*failure to fail*" as a poetic way to phrase "*persevere*": to determinedly keep going despite setbacks and failures. If he's speaking as an educator in an academic or scholastic context, he may be expressing his refusal to give students failing grades, and again using "*failure to fail*" as a poetic way of expressing his *refusal to give up* on students. The only difference is in the academic context, he's using *fail* transitively.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "phrase" as such, you could google to see how many people have used the combination. If your professor is the only hit, I shall not be very surprised. As to what the (bleep) (s)he is talking about, one can't tell without the rest of the passage. YMMV, but I would have stopped reading or left the hall after "abject/ecstatic failure to fail".